# SQL Server login with Windows authentication

Tags: sql-server, windows-authentication

If I open SQL Server Management Studio, I am able to login just fine, but if I try in my code, it returns an error

> login failed for user

This is my connection string:

```
this.ConnectionString = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=DanboligTest;User ID=dev\spInstall";

this.ConnectionString = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=DanboligTest;";
```

**EDIT** if I use the server explorer in VS then I can login fine.

No matter what I try Im not able to login like this. Can someone tell me what im doing wrong?

Comment: You can't specify a windows login. You can only use the currently logged in person or a SQL login (which has nothing to do with windows logins)

Comment: If I have doubts about a connectionstring i always go back to https://www.connectionstrings.com and find my fix. For SQL: https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/ - why are you mentioning 2 connectionstrings in your code example by the way? Surely you aren't assigning it twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add this line to you connection string

```
 Integrated Security=SSPI;
```

and remove the line

```
User ID=dev\spInstall
```

So all in all

```
 this.ConnectionString = "Integrated Security=SSPI; Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=DanboligTest;";
```

Comment: then it throws: Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\IUSR'.

Comment: I'm guessing it's passing that user from IIS, and it's not authenticated in SQL Server

Comment: your correct, i created an user with 'NT AUTHORITY\IUSR' and now it Works, thanks alot

Comment: @PeterHansen you should accept this answer as correct if it fixed your issue :)

Comment: @scsimon I was going to and have done it now. Just had to wait for the time to run Down so i could accept the answer

Comment: Awesome @PeterHansen